# Reject Enter from activating the click action

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to help with my new clicker game that I'm working on and I've stumbled upon a problem with adding a value to the "playerPoints" which is from launch 0. You need to click a button which is called "button_click" which will add +1 (++) to your "playerPoints". But there is a bug when you click the button and then hold the enter button it will act like a little auto clicker which I don't want. Is there a way how to prevent the enter key to add value when it is pressed or held down? Thanks in exchange.

```
          int playerPoints = 0;

          public void button_click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // main click button
          {
           playerPoints++;
           label_points.Text = playerPoints.ToString() + " BITS";
          }
```

Comment: Do you think this scenario is likely enough to be worth coding around?

Comment: I mean, I want to get some help from someone that knows the solution. + I want to overcome this bug so I can continue :)

Comment: If you don't want the button to act like a button (respond to keys) you might be better off using an image instead?

Comment: I would like to thank you for this idea. Although it works, it feels like it responds slowly to the click.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved by an great idea by: Dan Byström
If you don't want to make the button respond to keys like enter.
Use a simple image or label and link that function to the image_click or label_click

again thanks alot guys!

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the subject `Button`, it becomes the form's ActiveControl.  As part of the form's internal processing in setting the ActiveControl, the [Form.UpdateDefaultButton Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.updatedefaultbutton?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) is called.

> [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.updatedefaultbutton?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks)
>
> The UpdateDefaultButton method determines which button on the form raises its Click event when the user presses ENTER, according to the following priority:

To avoid having the subject button becoming the Default Button, override the form's UpdateDefaultButton method with something like this:

```
protected override void UpdateDefaultButton()
{
    if (ActiveControl == button_click)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        base.UpdateDefaultButton();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hook the KeyDown event instead of the Click event.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keydown

```
Button.KeyDown += Button_KeyDown;

// Handle the KeyDown event
private void Button_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   //increment your counter
}
```